# Encoding UTF-8 for Czech chars

Tags: encoding, utf-8, cp1250

I want to ask you, as a beginner, what basic settings for the document encoding are you doing with UTF-8?

An example how I do it below and am asking about repair if something is wrong. I want to rely on all devices in different browsers with different user settings will render the text as it should, so I will do the following:

- I use Notepad ++ , first in the Format tab choose "change the encoding to UTF-8 (if its already not)";
- Because I use `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` mostly or . `<!DOCTYPE html>`, then select the correct attribute for the meta tag in the head, so either `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` , respectively . `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

I'm concerned mainly about the Czech characters

Am I right or isn´t it that simple if I expect cooperation between HTML, PHP or JS, maybe MySQL?
Thank you for your answers and sorry for incomplete English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read text from a Database make sure that it is set to utf8 and that the columns are as well. Then you can use `SET NAMES UTF8` to make sure the connection encoding is utf8 as well. Just make it your first query to the databse.

Comment: Yes, had to use mysql_query, I got it, thank you. But is the solution of encoding settings above correct? For itself document. I know, this is really basic question, but I need some conviction from experienced programmer to avoid major problems with this common frequent problem. Thanks

Comment: I always use <meta charset="UTF-8" /> and I make sure my files are utf8 encoded. No problems at all.